# How to automatically increment a value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically I'm trying to make a formula that will put the number 0.25 in a column and then add 0.25 until it gets to 30. So basically I need it to look like:

```
0.25 
0.5 
0.75 
1 
1.25 etc.
```

Been looking all over the web and can't find any way to do this. Also I'm using Excel 2016 for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just enter the first couple of values, you can drag the range to 120 rows and Excel will fill in the values.  Select the filled range, click on the lower right corner, and drag.

If you need to do it with a formula, you could enter 0.25 in say A1.  In A2:

```
=IF(MAX(A$1:A1)=30,"",A1+0.25)
```

Copy or drag the formula down and any cells beyond what you need will be blank.

Comment: Tried doing this but it didn't work. Neither of them. First answer almost works but it added a 1 to the .25 instead of another .25. And the formula gives me an error message. I've attached a picture: https://imgur.com/cQ5qDa6. Hope you can help

Comment: For the dragging option, you may need another value for Excel to see the pattern (I'm using LO Calc and it guesses correctly with just two values).  Highlight the existing entries, then drag the mark in the lower right corner of the range.  My bad on the original formula, it created a circular reference.  Fixed it.

Comment: Tried doing more values didn't work, but the formula works great. Thanks so much for your help!